# IF/OR formula is not working correctly (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm trying to write an IF/OR formula so that when cell (J$4 = [value or value2]) it would pull a certain value.  However, when it is blank I want it to default to 0, but it would not.  It would pull the value even if blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(J$4="1120S",1120),INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 1",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0),0)
```

Comment: Without seeing a sample data set it's hard to know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: `OR(J$4="1120S",J$4=1120)`

Comment: the OR function should be changed to OR(J4="1120S",J4=1120)

Comment: @Scott Craner I just figured that out too.  It works when I define the second logic.  But out of curiosity, I don't know the difference between OR(J$4="1120S",J$4="1120") and OR(J$4="1120S",1120).  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(J$4="1120S",1120),INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 1",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0),0)
```

You should use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(J$4="1120S",J$4=1120),INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 1",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0),0)
```

---

Notice the change from:

```
OR(J$4="1120S",1120)
```

to:

```
OR(J$4="1120S",J$4=1120)
```

---

[image]

See more at: [OR() function - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between OR(J$4="1120S",J$4="1120") and OR(J$4="1120S",1120)

Comment: `OR(J$4="1120S",J$4="1120")` first check if cell `J4` value is equal to a `string` value of `1120S` and then, evaluates if cell `J4` value is equal to a `string` value of `1120`. The other formula, `OR(J$4="1120S",1120)` first evaluates if cell `J4` content is equal to a `string` value of `1120S`, and then evaluates the `integer` value of `1120` (which always return TRUE) - see the image that I've attached to my answer.

Comment: Now I understand.  Thank you!